# DataSource became null during the injection to EmployeeDAO

Tags: nullpointerexception, datasource

**application-context.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"/>
    <property name="username" value="scott"/>
    <property name="password" value="tiger"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="employeeDAO1"      class="com.santosh.spring.dao.impl.EmployeeDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg  ref="dataSource1" index="0" ></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="employeeService" class="com.santosh.spring.service.impl.EmployeeServicesImpl">
    <property name="employeeDao" ref="employeeDAO1"></property>
</bean>
```

In this `EmployeeDAOImpl` class `dataSource` became null, so I cannot connect to database:

**EmployeeDAOImpl class**

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO{

    private DataSource dataSource;
    public EmployeeDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource){
        dataSource=this.dataSource;
        System.out.println("Getting DataSourse");
        System.out.println(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public double getSalary(int empno) {

        Connection connection=null;
        try{
            /*Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "scott", "tiger");*/
            String GET_SALARY_BY_EMPNO="SELECT SAL FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ENO=?";
            //getting the connection
            //connection=dataSource.getConnection();
            System.out.println("Connection is-:"+connection);
            System.out.println("Connection-:"+connection);
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(GET_SALARY_BY_EMPNO);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, empno);
            ResultSet resultSet=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if(resultSet.next()){
                return resultSet.getDouble(1);
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Employee Not Found ");
        }
        catch(RuntimeException runtimeExp){
            System.out.println(runtimeExp);
        }//catch
        catch(Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }//catch
        finally{
            try{
                connection.close();
            }
            catch(Exception exception){

            }
        }//finally
        return 0;

    }//getSal
```

**EmployeeServiceImpl class**

```
public class EmployeeServicesImpl implements EmployeeServices {

    private EmployeeDAO employeeDao;

    public EmployeeDAO getEmployeeDao() {
        return employeeDao;
    }

    public void setEmployeeDao(EmployeeDAO employeeDao) {
        this.employeeDao = employeeDao;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean incrementSalary(int empno, double salary) {
        double esalary=employeeDao.getSalary(100);
        System.out.println("Employee Current Salary-:"+esalary);
        return true;
    }
```

While I am injecting `dataSource` into my `EmployeeDAO`, I'm getting null as data source, so I'm not connected to the database. I'm getting the output as:

> Connection is-:null
>   Connection-:null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: code how you calling dao please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
```

instead of

```
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
```